# How to use mock service worker to test vue apollo?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I have set up mock service worker to test my composition functions but get the error: `Apollo client with id default not found. Use provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup.`.

Guess I should use provideApolloClient but pasting that in [search](https://apollo.vuejs.org/) gives me nothing.

The docs show to [inject data in component](https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html) and mock schema (not getting that part). But I am not testing a component, I am trying to test a custom composition function (hook) and make sure it interfaces with useQuery correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message you get suggests that Apollo cannot fully render because it can't find any Apollo Client from the context. This may happen if you're calling a code that doesn't have the `ApolloProvider` with the `client` as its parent. Even if you're testing a hook, you would still have to render the hook wrapped in Apollo's Provider and supply the `client` instance as per Apollo's documentation. Take a look at how your React hook testing library suggests doing that.

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting using [`@testing-library/react-hooks`](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks):

```js
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { client } from './apollo-client'
import { myHook } from './myHook'

it('runs the hook as expected', () => {
  renderHook(() => myHook(), {
    wrapper({ children }) {
      return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
    }
  })
  // actions and assertions here
})
```

I know this won't directly translate to Vue but I'm certain there's an alternative for testing hooks in Vue. Hope this stirs you in the right direction.